# How do I handle correlated data points in classification problem where users generate multiple events?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, correlation, cross-validation, validation

If I have a data set containing multiple users' data with features $X$ and some class (let's assume binary for simplicity) that I want to classify, $Y$. A user can generate multiple "events" and $X$ as well as $Y$ might not be the same for each event. Each "event" is a discrete moment in time but surely each user's events are correlated by the mere virtue of being generated by the same person.

How do I deal with this in building a machine learning classifier for $Y$?

I have some ID to distinguish between users. If I ignore the ID and treat the data as independent I loose some information and also perhaps bias the classifier to work well on users for whom I have a lot of events. But if I keep only one event per user I loose a lot of information for cases where their behaviour could have been different with different (or the same) $Y$.

Is there any literature on dealing with cases such as this or any best practices?

Perhaps adding a feature to $X$ indicating if it is a first-time or current user or perhaps a running count on the number of events generated with that user for each data point?

I'd also possibly want to stratify my train/validation/test set to not contain the same users or... be stratified over time so that the validation/test set is later in time than the train set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have what is called [repeated-measures](/questions/tagged/repeated-measures), which is typically modeled using [mixed-model](/questions/tagged/mixed-model)s. I'd encourage you to look through questions carrying these two tags and maybe look at some textbooks.

In your specific case, you have a binary response, so a mixed logistic regression would be appropriate. In R, you can use the [`lme4` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) for this.

Alternatively, you could use ML tools like CARTs or Random Forests, including the ID for each observation as a feature. The question then is whether you want to classify a response from a new user or from one that you have seen in your training data. In the first case, your ID feature would contain a previously unobserved value, and your ML tool might choke on this. Mixed models can deal gracefully with such a situation.

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for the reply. You've given me a couple of terms to search for online.
Ideally I would be able to handle lots of new users (with the occasional repeat user), so perhaps mixed models would be better than CARTs/Random Forests.
In your opinion are mixed models still appropriate when the majority of events are new users?

Comment: I'd say that mixed models would be *especially* useful in such a situation. If you can meaningfully cluster your IDs and have a new user that you don't know yet but know the *cluster membership* of, you might be able to use hierarchical models.

Answer (score 2):

Stephan Kolassa already gave a great answer. I'd like to add some thoughts regarding the stratification. I can't stress enough that you must split data based on users (train/test/val), if you intend to evaluate performance for a new user. If you leak data of the same user between your different sets it will give you biased performance estimates.