# Classification on Dataset with multiple rows per person

Tags: classification, repeated-measures, feature-engineering

I have a data set where there are multiple rows per person. If person1 has 3 rows, out of 6 features, only couple of them change. The remaining features have the same values repeated. There are several rows per person because some variables change with time and some don’t. Therefore, there are multiple rows for each person. 3 years worth of data is being considered for the trial. While there could be at most 3 rows per person with couple of variables having different values each year, some candidates could have just 1 or 2 rows because they exited before the trial got completed or they might have entered in the 2 or 3rd year. Should I have just 1 row per person and make sure each rows in the data set is independent ?

Comment: What is the target / response variable, what do you want to predict with a classifier ?

Comment: You need to look at a linear mixed model, since (from what I can see) you are modelling a longitudinal study.

Comment: @steffen The attrition flag is the label I am trying to predict.

Comment: @learner ping is correct. Did you look at the questions [How do I handle correlated data points in classification problem where users generate multiple events?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/311422/how-do-i-handle-correlated-data-points-in-classification-problem-where-users-gen?rq=1) or [Classification Model with multiple records per user](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/440566/classification-model-with-multiple-records-per-user?rq=1) ? Do they help ? If not, why ? What is different ?

Comment: @steffen Thank you. Those posts were useful. My question is really can one drop the ID and Year columns and run tree models like RF to classify ? Would that be right ? Is there an iid or any other assumptions being violated? Having 2 or 3 rows would capture whether the student is in 1st or 2nd or 3rd year of study is a valid argument? My choices are, 1. I can keep multiple rows WITHOUT student ID and year columns 2. Have the current state of the student only which would mean having 1 row. I feel option 1 is incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have repeated measures on students over time and the outcome variable is binary.

To handle the repeated measures, a mixed effects model can be used with random intercepts for students.

Since the outcome is binary, a (logistic) generalised linear mixed model would be appropriate.

Another approach would be to consider the data as right-censored and fit a time-to-failure model such as cox proportional hazards, however with a maximum of only 3 time points, this doesn't really make sense.